# failed to create package for iOS of kivy app in mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ios, macos

We are trying to create iOS package for our Kivy app.For this purpose we followed the instruction step by step from the following link:

http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

When we entered the command :
sudo sh build-all.sh
we got a log which includes:

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ffi-40B3EFCE4526D95F.o ios/src/arm/ffi.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/sysv.o ios/src/arm/sysv.S normal armv7 assembler-with-cpp com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

X code :X code 6.1
OS: mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite
kivy:1.8.0
python:2.7

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?